# R: detect words and punctuation marks in text

Tags: regex, r, text, detection, grepl

I have some naturally occuring text:

```
   text="word1 word2 word3. word4, word5 word6 word7"
```

And some elements that I want to detect in that text:

```
elements=c("word2","word6 word7",".",",")
```

However,

```
 elements[sapply(paste0("\\<",elements,"\\>"),grepl,text)]
```

only returns the unigram "word2" and the bigram "word6 word7". The period and comma, which are in the text, are not detected.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the square brackets, since sqaure brackets are special meta charcaters in regex which means a character class.

```
> text="word1 word2 word3. word4, word5 word6 word7"
> elements=c("word2","word6 word7",".",",")
> elements[sapply(paste0(elements),grepl,text, fixed=T)]
[1] "word2"       "word6 word7" "."           ","
```

Comment: thanks! So, in which cases do you use \\< >\\ and [ ] ?

Comment: that does not come from me

Comment: `\\<` matches between a word char and a non-word char and `\\>` matches between a non-word char and word char. so `.` which exits in `3. ` won't satisfy this because there  isn't a word char exits after dot. Likewise the same for comma also.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements[sapply(paste0("[",elements,"]"),grepl,text)] does the job.
```